# Linux SETFACL to not go out of /home

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems, acl, shared-directory

So I've been testing ACL's in Linux and they work as intended. I have, for example, this folder where I've stablished permissions for users belonging to the grupo `share`. So far, so good...

```
lucas@lucas:/$ getfacl testAcl/
# file: testAcl/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:share:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:share:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

This works fine. Once the ACL has been set, users can or cannot go into the specified folder, as per their group membership.

But I'm interested in something a little different: users usually log into the server, and they land in their `/home/user` folder. How can I set up an ACL so users can't leave the `/home` directory but also be able to go deeper inside `/home/share`, for example?

I've though about two options so far:

- All users belonging to group `adm` CAN leave /home, or ...
- All users belonging to group `share` CANNOT leave /home.

How can I set that up using `setfacl`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "leave" you mean using the `cd` command, then the `cd` command requires execute permissions on directories, so in order to prevent people from leaving the home directory you'll have to revoke their execute permissions on sibling directories of `/home/` such as `/usr/` and `/bin/`.

Unfortunately, the way commands such as `ls` and `cp` are executed is that the shell executes `/bin/ls`, which means it has to traverse `/bin/`, which requires execute permissions.

Meaning, if they need to be able to execute `/bin/ls`, they also need to be able to do `cd /bin/`. Therefore, there's no way to prevent users from leaving `/home/` without making all the commands available under `/home/`.